# How do I define a variable being used in an E.js file that is defined when rendering?

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs

I know this might be mediocre, but i'm trying to learn E.js..

I am trying to create a login system, and whenever the login fails, I'd like to display a message.

An example

When the login rejects:

```js
if (!targetUser)
            return res.render('login', {
                badLogin: true
            });
```

On the .ejs file

```html
<% if(badLogin === true){ %>
    <h1>foo</h1>
<% } %>
```

I'm getting an undefined error, but I'm not sure how to define this. Could anybody help me?

I want the heading "foo" to only display when badLogin is equal to true.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you paste the error message that you get?

Comment: @happyhardik badLogin is not defined
    at eval (E:\dev\jchipwebsite\pages\login.ejs:13:8)
    at login (E:\dev\jchipwebsite\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:679:17)
    at tryHandleCache (E:\dev\jchipwebsite\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:272:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (E:\dev\jchipwebsite\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:478:10)
    at View.render (E:\dev\jchipwebsite\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (E:\dev\jchipwebsite\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)

Comment: What if there is a targetUser? do you set badLogin: false? Can you paste more of your real code, there seems to be something wrong.

Comment: @happyhardik The rest of the code is irrelevant. Don't worry about the users. I just need to know how to get badLogin defined so I can use it in the file

Comment: @happyhardik According to all the guides I've read it should just be defined by doing that rendering function. It doesn't matter what happens if there is a user, that code is not the problem

Comment: I think there is a problem with your code or setup. When you set `res.render('login',{foo:"bar"});` and do `<% if(foo=="bar") {...} %>` it should work.

Comment: @happyhardik The same should go for a Boolean then I assume

Answer (score 0):

Adding a check to see if the variable is set should solve your problem.

```
<% if(badLogin && badLogin === true){ %>
    <h1>foo</h1>
<% } %>
```

Comment: @happyharddik The problem is not that there is no value, the problem is it isn't defined at all

Comment: You don't define variables in EJS files and then use them. The idea is to pass the variables from your controllers.

Comment: If the variable is always undefined in your EJS file, then there is something wrong with your setup.

Comment: Well this is what is working for me, your solution provided the same outcome as the original code.

Answer (score 0):

Such a simple answer actually, I had to just make the variable right above it.

```js
<% let badLogin;
    if(badLogin === true){ %>
        <h1>foo</h1>
    <% } %>
```